# TortoiseHg Mercurial Repository: BigFile extension to manage big binary files in the repository

Tags: mercurial, repository, binaryfiles, mercurial-bigfiles

I would like to ask the way to implement big file extension in TortoiseHg Mercurial (version 2.9), to manage the big binary files in the repository.

Since my project is growing, the binary files are also changing and growing in term of the file size. So, as I check-in the binary files (of course including others file as well),just because the binary files cannot be merged, this post a threat to the limited size of the Mercurial repository and one day the repository will be full and probably crashed.

I had searched and study about the largefiles extension of Mercurial, but this is not the way that I am looking for, because the largefile extension still keep the largefile (actually same as big files) in the remote repository (center repository), although the local repository can have a lesser space being occupied, since as long as there are the largefiles copies at the center repository, we can download it anytime we want. But, this still occupy the repository space.

Therefore, I am thinking of keeping all the big binary files outside of repository and each revision will have their own link to their big binary files. So, the repository just keep the link to the big binary files only, and seems that the big file extension can serve this purpose.

However, I just can't find the big file extension in the Mercurial setting. And I also look through [BigfilesExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BigfilesExtension) and follow the implementation method of big extension, by editing the .hg/hgrc file. But, this cannot work.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated;)